# Adding emoji to a Hugo page variable

Tags: hugo

How to add an emoji to a Hugo page variable? E.g. inside the title in the following code snippet:

```
date = "2016-11-20T12:00:00"
draft = false
tags = ["Fun"]
title = "Went sporting :heart:"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hugo has two ways of handling Emojis.

Setting `enableEmoji=true` in your site config will handle emoji syntax like `:heart:` in your markdown content.

For titles etc. you must use the `emojify` template func, so in your template:

`{{ .Title | emojify }}`