# How can I insert an emoji on config.toml in Hugo rendered website?

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I want to add a cloud emoji on my webpage's footer, but apparently the `config.toml` file doesn't support emojis

```
 [params]
      footerText   = ":cloud: David Jorquera - 2020"
```

...is rendered as text.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why that doesn't work?**

Hugo uses the [emojify function](https://gohugo.io/functions/emojify/) to parse templates for emojis substitution. But it doesn't apply such functions to the configuration.

To do so, you would have needed to pass your variable to the function in the template using `{{ .footerText | emojify }}` as documented in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41280669/1930997).

**Use directly UTF-8 characters in configuration**

Your TOML configuration file can be considered as an UTF-8 document.

As such, you can directly add the emoji in the config value:

```
[params]
    footerText = "☁️ David Jorquera – 2020"
```

This sample uses an emoji and a dash between your name and the year.

Comment: There is also the question to DISPLAY those characters, and for that, `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` in HTML files (`<head>` section) can help.

Comment: Thank you! I'm very new to Hugo so I just need a little extra help to accept your answer as a solution: ¿where is the template that I need to modify? If I'm close, the theme that I'm using has the following folders in the layouts folder: "_default", "gallery", "partials", "posts", and two html files: "404" and "index".

Comment: All right! I replaced the content of themes/layouts/partials/footer.html from `{{ .Site.Params.footerText | markdownify }}` to `{{ .Site.Params.footerText | emojify }}` (It had to be replaced instead of added, and maintaining the param name). It worked :)